# converting seconds to minutes but without changing the format

Tags: microsoft-excel

The thing is I cant use "*Time*" format, so I need to convert seconds to minutes with "*Text*" or "*General*" format.

```
=MINUTE(VALUE(LEFT(G1,FIND("s",G1)-1))/86400
```

This is what I use to get minutes but I forgot that the data can exceed up to an hour. What's the easiest way to compute total minutes from seconds without changing the format?

[image: Seconds to mins image]

(don't mind the third column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the Minute and Value functions and divide the Left function by 60 not 86400

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("s",A1)-1)/60
```

[image]

If you only want the full minutes then You can wrap the whole in INT()

```
=INT(LEFT(A1,FIND("s",A1)-1)/60)
```

[image]